# Should we rename the "roleplaying" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently went through the questions tagged [roleplaying](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roleplaying) and cleaned out a few instances where the tag seemed to have been placed simply because the question was about RPGs.  In one or two cases, it was the only tag on the question but was easily and more appropriately replaced with other existing tags.

Does anyone have suggestions for how we can rename this tag to more clearly reflect its purpose (intended for questions about how to act in-character) separate from general RPG questions?

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, we might want to consider a [roleplaying-technique](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roleplaying-technique) tag to cover the nuts-and-bolts of playing roles. I think that'd be slightly more inclusive than [character-roleplaying](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-roleplaying), because it could encompass, for example inter-player techniques that enhance roleplay without being about how to play a character, and other roleplaying methodology stuff…

Comment: I like roleplaying-technique as a rename for the current roleplaying tag.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe [character-roleplaying](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-roleplaying)?

Comment: To be distinguished from [character-acting], I guess.  Good enough I think, +1.

Answer (score 2):

how-to-roleplay?
roleplay-in-character?

(tags match regardless of position in the words, so typing rolep will match both of those)

Comment: I don't like "how-to," seems "noob only."  "character-roleplay"?

Comment: @mxyzplk Yeah, that. I answered before I saw this comment.

Answer (score 2):

IMO, we can just periodically weed through the tag and get rid of the uses that don't match. A tag wiki would probably help too (although you don't see it when adding tags to a question...).

The main issue I've had with this in the past is that there aren't many terms for playing a role that are as widely used. And most of the natural runners up don't include the term "roleplay" unless we force it in.